# Silverlight: VisualState Animation Being Overridden Somehow

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, custom-controls, visualstatemanager, animation

I've got a rather complicated custom control that would boggle your mind if I showed you all of the code. ;)  In general it's a panel displaying multiple controls.  You can think of it as a custom list box.  (Please don't tell me to use a listbox, I've been there and it doesn't meet my needs completely).

So, I set some animations in a VisualStateManager. Here's what happens:

- When I **hover** over one of my child controls, I expect the *MouseOver* state to fire. It does.
- When I **select** one of my child controls I expect the *Selected* state to fire and it does.
- When I **select** a different child control, the *Selected* state fires as well
- When I go back to my first child control I selected, and **select** it, the *Selected* state is shown to fire (by debug statements in my code) but the *MouseOver* animation is displayed.

Is there some issue with animations able to be overridden somehow or a problem between the MouseOver and Selected states I'm not aware of?

Here's my VSM markup:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">       
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.150000" Storyboard.TargetName="Backdrop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="DarkGray"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="00:00:00.150000" Storyboard.TargetName="Backdrop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectedStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="1" Storyboard.TargetName="Backdrop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Purple"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Duration="1" Storyboard.TargetName="Backdrop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And here's my GoToState() logic:

private void GoToState(bool useTransitions)
{
    TestingVariables("Inside GoToState");

```
if (_isSelected)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_thumbnail.ShortFileName + " firing Selected VSM");
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Selected", useTransitions);
}
else if (_wasSelected)
{
    _wasSelected = false;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_thumbnail.ShortFileName + " firing Unselected");
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Unselected", useTransitions);
}
else if (_isMouseOver)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_thumbnail.ShortFileName + " firing MouseOver VSM");
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "MouseOver", useTransitions);
}
else
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_thumbnail.ShortFileName + " firing Normal VSM");
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", useTransitions);
}
```

}

So, I can see which VisualStateManger.GoToState() method is fired and the call to TestingVariables() is just a method I use to write out the conditional flags I'm using to determine which visual state to fire.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer to this question: [Custom styled listbox - how can I keep the style for a selected item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596026/custom-styled-listbox-how-can-i-keep-the-style-for-a-selected-item/3596570#3596570)