# Animating same property from mutually exclusive VisualStateGroups

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visualstatemanager

My question is simply: is it even possible?

Suppose I want to style a `ListBoxItem` such that it has a black foreground by default, blue when selected, and red when the mouse is over it. I ended up with something like this:

```
<!-- assume the default foreground color is black -->
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>

                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>

            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>

                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="Blue" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The problem is that the `ListBoxItem` class has correctly placed selection states in their own visual state group, separate to common states such as mouse over. That means that a `ListBoxItem` can be in both the selected and mouse over state.

If the `ListBoxItem` is selected and correctly displayed in blue, mousing over it will revert it to black because it transitions back to the normal state.

Is there any way for me to handle this without resorting to subclassing `ListBoxItem` and adding my own custom states? Everything I've read suggests that it is not possible, but it seems ridiculously limiting to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically asking for Foreground to be black AND blue at the same time. Now that is just impossible. This conflict could be resolved if individual states had precedence, like MouseOver > Selected > Normal > Unselected. But it would introduce unnecessary complication to already complicated visual state manager. Typically this situation is resolved by adding new element and animating that element's properties in one of the conflicting state groups.

- [Custom styled listbox - how can I keep the style for a selected item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596026/custom-styled-listbox-how-can-i-keep-the-style-for-a-selected-item/)